# Simulating a Browser-Image upload to imgur

Tags: c#, http, httpwebrequest, imgur

I sniffed the traffic between my browser (Firefox Dev.Ed.) and imgur during an image-upload, because I want to be able to upload images **without** using the official API.
You can download the traffic-capture through my dropbox link:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/6xfh6mdf03fe4dz/imgur_sniff.pcapng?dl=0

This is how I interpret that capture:
At first, each upload becomes an `Upload-Session ID` , which is received by sending a request to http://imgur.com/upload/start_session. The incoming response from this connection contains the Header-Attribute `Set-Cookie` which contains this ID.
After this (new TCP-Stream in Wireshark-sniff), http://imgur.com/upload/checkcaptcha?total_uploads=1 is called, where `total_uploads` is a `GET`- Attribute which probably expresses the amount of images which are going to be uploaded.

The following is the response of request above:

```
5d
...........VJI,IT..V./K-....,)V.2.Q*-..OL.O./.+Q.22..Q*.MNN-.J......%.%.@...A-.......p_..G...
0
```

I don't know what this means, should this stand for a string?
The next step would be requesting http://imgur.com/crossdomain.xml, but I think this is not necessary, because only redundant information was sent.

The next TCP-Stream is the probably most interesting one:
http://imgur.com/upload is called via POST (Multipart-FormData), 
and the last bodypart is the `OCTET`-Stream of the image which should be uploaded.
The response contains the link of the image.

Now here is my implementation:

```
// Getting the Upload-Session
HttpWebRequest sessionRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("http://imgur.com/upload/start_session");
sessionRequest.Host = "imgur.com";
sessionRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0";
sessionRequest.Accept = "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01";
sessionRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3");
sessionRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
sessionRequest.Headers.Add("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
sessionRequest.Referer = "http://imgur.com/";
sessionRequest.KeepAlive = true;
sessionRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) sessionRequest.GetResponse();
string imgurSession = response.Headers.Get("Set-Cookie");

MultiPartFormData formData = new MultiPartFormData();
formData.Add("Filename", imageFile.Name);
formData.Add("forceAnnonymous", "false");
formData.Add("total_uploads", "1");
formData.Add("sid", imgurSession.Split(';')[0].Split('=')[1]);
formData.Add("catify", "0");
formData.Add("current_upload", "1");
formData.Add("create_album", "0");
formData.Add("layout", "b");
formData.Add("gallery_submit", false.ToString());
formData.Add("album_title", "Optional Album Title");
formData.Add("edit", "0");
formData.AddCustomEntry("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Filedata\"; filename=\"" +
                        imageFile.Name + "\"" + Environment.NewLine + "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" + Environment.NewLine
                        + Environment.NewLine);
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(imageFile.FullName, FileMode.Open);
byte[] fileBuffer = new byte[imageFile.Length];
byte[] lastFormData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(formData.CreateEntry("Upload", "Sumbit Query" + Environment.NewLine +
                                                                    "------------" + formData.Ticks + "--"));

HttpWebRequest uploadRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("http://imgur.com/upload");
uploadRequest.Method = "POST";
uploadRequest.Accept = "text/*";
uploadRequest.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=----------" + formData.Ticks;
uploadRequest.UserAgent = "Shockwave Flash";
uploadRequest.Host = "imgur.com";
uploadRequest.ContentLength = fileBuffer.Length + formData.Length + lastFormData.Length;
uploadRequest.KeepAlive = true;
uploadRequest.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

Stream uploadStream = uploadRequest.GetRequestStream();
uploadStream.Write(formData.ToBytes(), 0, formData.Length);
while (fileStream.Read(fileBuffer, 0, fileBuffer.Length) != 0)
{
    uploadStream.Write(fileBuffer, 0, fileBuffer.Length);
}
uploadStream.Write(lastFormData, 0, lastFormData.Length);
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(uploadRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
```

How you can see I **do not** access http://imgur.com/upload/checkcaptcha?, because I did not see any new information and I would have to perform lots of requests, how you can see when you open the corresponding TCP-Stream in Wireshark.
The response I am receivng is the following:

> da
>   {"data":{"error":{"code":1003,"message":"[2-bromobutan]: File type invalid > (application/octet-stream)","type":"Exception_UploadError","exception":{}},"request":"/upload","method":"POST"},"success":false,"status":500}
>   0

I really took lot of care to rebuild the last upload-request, so that Wireshark shows me, that my request to http://imgur.com/upload is exactly the same as the reqqest the browser sent. Nevertheless, I am getting an error. Ok, there is still some difference:
The Browser sends his requests with the `Cookie-Attribute` in the header, which looks like this:

```
__cfduid=df2407e2f959c4382aaf466c62265995a1418721431; __qca=P0-647698388-1419247516502; o=0.40444; m_sort=viral; m_window=day; m_section=hot; OX_plg=swf|shk|pm; __gads=ID=3bfd01a8b049d7c8:T=1419248272:S=ALNI_MZiowWAL9UL03fWOwJTV58emtv6xQ; IMGURSESSION=o8dkrlfmiufhtvga55898eceb4; _nc=1; UPSERVERID=i-362e5bdc; _ga=GA1.2.761672825.1419247517; __utmt=1; optimizelyEndUserId=oeu1419355284536r0.03670886438339949; __utma=247341212.761672825.1419247517.1419255358.1419355284.3; __utmb=247341212.3.10.1419355284; __utmc=247341212; __utmz=247341212.1419247517.1.1.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided); optimizelySegments=%7B%221503675771%22%3A%22gc%22%2C%221505515733%22%3A%22false%22%2C%221506465808%22%3A%22direct%22%2C%221717910483%22%3A%22none%22%2C%221893480508%22%3A%22true%22%2C%221938330135%22%3A%22true%22%2C%222025850214%22%3A%22true%22%2C%222359290357%22%3A%22true%22%7D; optimizelyBuckets=%7B%7D
```

while I am only sending the Session-ID as bodypart in the Multipart-FormdData Upload (, which the Browser-Upload does too).
What do you think is the cause of this failure and how can I solve that?

**NOTE: The Wireshark-sniff does not contain the first request to  http://imgur.com/upload/start_session, I do not know why this wasn't being captured, but I described that TCP-Stream enough.**

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but in the video, the dev tries to upload an image via the API.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: FYI, all of your streams, and your WebResponse objects need to be in `using` blocks. Also your `StreamReader`.

Comment: @JohnSaunders thanks for the advice, I am going to implement it.

Comment: @JohnSaunders The second TCP-Stream which starts with a request to /checkcaptcha? causes a few other requests, including the real upload-request. How can I implement this in C#, that I request more than one URL sequentially, so that the same TCP-Stream is used?

Comment: You mean the same TCP connection? Why does that matter? Is that a requirement of the server? HTTP is a request/response protocol. I don't believe there's any guarantee of using the same connection, even if keep-alive is requested in the headers. See [`KeepAlive` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.keepalive.aspx). Note that the default for HTTP 1.1 is `true`, so `Connection: Keep-alive` is sent by default.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to upload to http://imgur.com/upload/start_session

Checking http://imgur.com/robots.txt yields this:

```
# robots

User-agent: *
Disallow: /account/
Disallow: /delete/
Disallow: /download/
Disallow: /logout/
Disallow: /removalrequest/
Disallow: /upload/
Disallow: /1/
Disallow: /2/
Disallow: /3/
Sitemap: /gallery/sitemap.xml
```

They are very explicit about not automating requests to /upload/. So you shouldn't do it. Also, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0" is a firefox user agent, not the useragent of a script. Lying about your identity is really bad form. The site maintainer has provided instructions to stay away, you should really just learn to respect the conditions imposed by the OWNER of the site you're trying to access.

Just stop now and use the official API. There are no excuses for what you're trying to do here.